# Converting array to json in react application

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

In my react code I have items as an array in my state.

```
items[]
```

I was able to populate items array with few data and need to pass it to my web service.
First I need to convert that array to json. This is just crashing for me when I do the
Json.stringify.

Is there a different way to do it in react application?

```
storeDataInDatabase(){

    const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(this.props.items);

    console.log(myObjStr);
}
```

Comment: You said `state` initially then use `props` in your example. Which is it? What is the error? "just crashing for me" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: What is `items[]`?  It looks like you forgot a string in a property accessor, but you're saying it's an array.

Comment: If your items = [1, 2, 3], it will becomes '[1, 2, 3]' when you do JSON.stringify(items). I don't think you can convert array to json since json is a format. It is not a data structure. I think you mean converting array to object right?

Comment: Yes I think it is converting array to object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSON.stringify(..)` will convert your array the right way.
The serialized object would be something like:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But like you wrote in your first sentence, you are setting the items array to state. In think in a way like this:
`this.setState({ items })`
If so, you have to get the array right from your state in your component:

```
storeDataInDatabase() {
  const { items } = this.state;
  const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(items);
  console.log(myObjStr);
}
```

Comment: This looks more like what am looking for. I will try it now