# Updating flatList in two different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have Task, and task are created in a new component. They simply add the information to the array that stores all of the tasks.

I tried creating a global boolean called refresh(I know global isn't best practice, I just need to get this working, I don't mind about best practice right now). Then I set extradata = {global.refresh} and I set global.refresh = true every time the page is opened, but it doesn't do anything.

I could really appreciate someone to tell me what i'm doing wrong.

```html
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  global.refresh = false;
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  var currentDate = new Date();
   var formatedDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
   console.log(formatedDate)
   var one = {
     name:'Dishwasher',
   task:"Clean",
   time:formatedDate}
    var two = {
      name:'Fishwasher',
      task:'<lean',
      time:formatedDate
    }
  global.obj = [
    one,
    two,
      ]
          return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="New Task"
        accessibilityLabel="Create a new Task"
        onPress={() => 
          {
          navigation.navigate('NewTask')
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
      data = {obj}
      extraData={global.refresh}
      renderItem={({ item }) => 
          <View>
            <Task
              name={item.name}
              description={item.task}
              time={item.time}/>
          </View>
          }/>
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  )
}
```

In my newTask component, I simply add to the obj array and I set global.refresh = !global.refresh.

```html
class NewTask extends Component {
  state = {
    item: 'Car',
    name:'',
  };
  updateItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({item: item})
  }
  updateName = (name) => {
    this.setState({name: name})
  }
  
  render() {

    return (

      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.item}
          onValueChange={this.updateItem}>
          <Picker.Item label="Car" value="Car" />
          <Picker.Item label="HVAC Unit" value="HVAC" />
          <Picker.Item label="Fridge" value="Fridge" />
          <Picker.Item label="Smoke Detector" value="Smoke" />
          <Picker.Item label="Dryer" value="Dryer" />
          <Picker.Item label="Water Heater" value="water" />

        </Picker>
          <TextInput
          placeholder = "Name: "
          label='Name: '
          value={this.state.name}
          onChangeText={this.updateName}>

        </TextInput>
        
        <Button
        title = "Create Task"
        onPress={() => {
          //Adds data - removed for sake of space.
           }
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        }
        >

        </Button>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please if someone could help me that would be amazing. I've been stuck at this for so long. I've tried to read docs but it doesn't make sense to me with it being in two different components. I know I'm supposed to use this.state but I don't get how.

I don't need the best solution, just a solution.

Comment: what is actually your objective ? are you trying to use the flatlist to show the value of your textinput box and picker item chosen ?

Comment: I’m trying to have the flat list show a list off all of the tasks. When a new task is made, I want it to be permanently shown in the flat list. So yes, it should show the value of the text box and picker added on to the current array.

Comment: Oh in that case please trigger a push (push the data to the end of the array). For example this.setState(prevState => ({
  myArray: [...prevState.myArray, {"name": "object"}]
}))

Comment: I currently push onto the array obj.push({code for one of that task}) how do I add in that state part? And how does that help the flat list update?

Comment: use JSON.stringify(..) to convert your array to json. The flatlist gets data from a state in json format see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581233/converting-array-to-json-in-react-application . Such as in a Flatlist : data={this.state.dataSource}